# calling javascript function using onkeyup

Tags: javascript, html, function, onkeyup

I created a function to enable/disable a submit button, and I want it to run when user types something in a text field.

**Here is my code:**

```
<form name="sidebarPostMessageForm" action="../app/NewMessageAsynch.action">
    <input type="hidden" name="conversationId" value="${conversationId}"/>
    <lalahtml:textarea id="messageText" name="messageText" onkeyup="enableDisablePostButton();" ></lalahtml:textarea>
    <input type="button" name="postMessage" id="postMessage" onclick="if(this.form.messageText.value.trim().length>0){sidebar_postMessage();this.disabled='disabled'}" value="<ezmi18n:message key="doSendMessage.Label" />"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function enableDisablePostButton(){
    if (document.getElementById("messageText").value.trim() == "") {
        document.getElementById("postMessage").disabled="disabled";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("postMessage").disabled="";
    }
}
</script>
```

When I test it, I get the following javascript error:

**Error:**

ReferenceError: enableDisablePostButton is not defined
enableDisablePostButton();

[image: debugging with firebug]

It's like if the function enableDisablePostButton() did not exist... Does anyone know why and what can I do?

Comment: Seems to work okay when I try it .. is there more to your script?

Comment: no.. this is all.. :S

Comment: @periback2 try setup a jsfiddle, I tried and it worked for me.

Comment: Do you load that in a no javascript browser?

Comment: Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakschu/yxE2D/) i cleaned it up a bit.. Watch the console.

Comment: yes.. the javascript is enabled in all my browsers (i'm testing in FF)

Comment: @Uby, I see in jsfiddle it's working.. I just don't get what can possibly be wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem, guys! In fact, the javascript block wasn't being loaded because it was being fetched asynchronously (ajax). I found out this now and I set the javascript code in the onkeyup attribute directly:

```
onkeyup="this.form.messageText.value.trim() == ''? this.form.postMessage.disabled='disabled': this.form.postMessage.disabled='';"
```

thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think placing the script tag above the form tag should do the trick.
The enableDisablePostButton function is defined after the form tag, so it is not able to find the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function enableDisablePostButton(){
    if (document.getElementById("messageText").value.trim() == "") {
        document.getElementById("postMessage").disabled="disabled";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("postMessage").disabled="";
    }
}
</script>
<form name="sidebarPostMessageForm" action="../app/NewMessageAsynch.action">
    <input type="hidden" name="conversationId" value="${conversationId}"/>
    <lalahtml:textarea id="messageText" name="messageText"     onkeyup="enableDisablePostButton();" ></lalahtml:textarea>
    <input type="button" name="postMessage" id="postMessage" onclick="if(this.form.messageText.value.trim().length>0){sidebar_postMessage();this.disabled='disabled'}" value="<ezmi18n:message key="doSendMessage.Label" />"/>
</form>
```

Comment: for convention, all javascript code/files should be added after all the html code... this should not solve the problem :/